# Building a D3 table with json and comma delimited array

Tags: d3.js, html-table

I'm trying to build an html table from a 2D array using a row for each array element and a cell for each string in the row. I get a cell for each character instead. I've tried some combinations for splitting the strings by comma, but haven't one that works. How do I get

onetwothree

http://jsfiddle.net/johnpoole/BfTWP/

```
var json_data = ["one,two,three","red,green,blue"];
var table = d3.select("body").append("table");
var rows = table.selectAll("tr").data(json_data).enter().append("tr");
rows.selectAll("td").data(function(d){return d;}).enter().append("td").text(function(d)   {return d;});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line needs to return `d.split(",")` to break the string into an array. Otherwise, JS iterates through the characters in the string.

Alternatively, you could keep the code as is and change the data to:

```
var json_data = [["one","two","three"],["red","green","blue"]];
```

[jsFiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/chriswilsondc/BfTWP/1/) both ways.

Comment: Thanks, the split was what I trying for.